# issue attaching/adding an entity object which is detached from the DB Context?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am fairly new to EF and seem to have become a bit stuck with the following issue..

I have the following situation.

Two applications using the same database, and have both loaded the context at the same time displaying the same information.
Application 1 then goes and deletes a entity and updates the database with savechanges.
Application 2 then goes and saves back the same modified entity.

We are using an updategraph to recurse through the tree and save all the entities to the database context.
However, when we come to saving the deleted entity, this doesn't exist in the db context obtained from the database but we want to add this back to the database.

I have tried doing an ADD, but this gives us a multiplicity error as it is trying to add the full tree back to the context!

Any ideas please?

The following is a code snippet from the updategraph extension method. (http://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff)

```
private static void RecursiveGraphUpdate<T>(DbContext context, T dataStoreEntity, T updatingEntity, UpdateMember member) where T:class
    {
        if (member.IsCollection)
        {
            // We are dealing with a collection
            var updateValues = (IEnumerable)member.Accessor.GetValue(updatingEntity, null);
            var dbCollection = (IEnumerable)member.Accessor.GetValue(dataStoreEntity, null);
            var keyFields = context.GetKeysFor(updateValues.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
            var dbHash = MapCollectionToDictionary(keyFields, dbCollection);

            // Iterate through the elements from the updated graph and try to match them against the db graph.
            List<object> additions = new List<object>();
            foreach (object updateItem in updateValues)
            {
                var key = CreateHash(keyFields, updateItem);

                // try to find in db collection
                object dbItem;
                var itemID = updateItem.GetType().GetProperty("ID");

                if (dbHash.TryGetValue(key, out dbItem))
                {

                    var property = updateItem.GetType().GetProperty("Deleted");
                    bool ysn = property.GetValue(updateItem, null).ToString() == "True" ? true : false;
                    if (ysn)
                    {
                        context.Entry(dbItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(updateItem);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // If we own the collection
                    if (member.IsOwned)
                    {
                        context.Entry(dbItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(updateItem); // match means we are updating

                        foreach (var childMember in member.Members)
                            RecursiveGraphUpdate(context, dbHash[key], updateItem, childMember);
                    }

                    dbHash.Remove(key); // remove to leave only db removals in the collection
                }

                else
                    additions.Add(updateItem);
            }

            // Removal of dbItem's left in the collection
            foreach (var dbItem in dbHash.Values)
            {
                var property = dbItem.GetType().GetProperty("Deleted");
                bool ysn = property.GetValue(dbItem, null).ToString() == "True" ? true : false;
                if (ysn)
                {
                    // Own the collection so remove it completely.
                    if (member.IsOwned)
                        context.Set(dbItem.GetType()).Remove(dbItem);

                    dbCollection.GetType().GetMethod("Remove").Invoke(dbCollection, new[] { dbItem });
                }
            }

            // Add elements marked for addition
            foreach (object newItem in additions)
            {
                if (!member.IsOwned)
                    context.Set(newItem.GetType()).Attach(newItem);

                // Otherwise we will add to object
                dbCollection.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(dbCollection, new[] { newItem });
            }
        }
        else // not collection
        {
            var dbvalue = member.Accessor.GetValue(dataStoreEntity, null);
            var newvalue = member.Accessor.GetValue(updatingEntity, null);
            if (dbvalue == null && newvalue == null) // No value
                return;

            // If we own the collection then we need to update the entities otherwise simple relationship update
            if (!member.IsOwned)
            {
                if (dbvalue != null && newvalue != null)
                {
                    var keyFields = context.GetKeysFor(newvalue.GetType());
                    var newKey = CreateHash(keyFields, newvalue);
                    var updateKey = CreateHash(keyFields, dbvalue);
                    if (newKey == updateKey)
                        return; // do nothing if the same key
                }

                if (context.Entry(newvalue).State == EntityState.Detached)
                    context.Set(newvalue.GetType()).Attach(newvalue);

                member.Accessor.SetValue(dataStoreEntity, newvalue, null);
                context.Entry(newvalue).Reload();
                // TODO would like to do this: context.Entry(newvalue).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                // However it seems even though we are in an unchanged state EF will still update the database if the original values are different.
            }
            else
            {
                if (dbvalue != null && newvalue != null)
                {
                    // Check if the same key, if so then update values on the entity
                    var keyFields = context.GetKeysFor(newvalue.GetType());
                    var newKey = CreateHash(keyFields, newvalue);
                    var updateKey = CreateHash(keyFields, dbvalue);

                    // perform update if the same
                    if (updateKey == newKey)
                    {
                        context.Entry(dbvalue).CurrentValues.SetValues(newvalue);
                        context.Entry(dbvalue).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    else
                        member.Accessor.SetValue(dataStoreEntity, newvalue, null);
                }
                else
                    member.Accessor.SetValue(dataStoreEntity, newvalue, null);

                // TODO
                foreach (var childMember in member.Members)
                    RecursiveGraphUpdate(context, dbvalue, newvalue, childMember);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to mention, we are using code-first.